# Circle Progress Bar for Swift Count down

Tags: swift, progress-bar

Inside the circle progress bar there is a constantly changing number (eg 250, 300, 1000). Whenever I click, the number will decrease and circle progress bar will move. I did it with the time counter. But I want to do it with my control. So when I click the button it will move, if I don't click it won't move.
My code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let shapeLAyer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    let progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
       
        
        let center = view.center
        
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: 2*CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        
        progressLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        // ui edits
       
        progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        
        progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        
        //progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        
        progressLayer.lineCap = .round
        
        progressLayer.lineWidth = 20.0
        
        view.layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
      
        
       
        
        
        shapeLAyer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        
        shapeLAyer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        
        shapeLAyer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        
        shapeLAyer.lineWidth = 10
        
        shapeLAyer.lineCap = .round
        
        shapeLAyer.strokeEnd = 0

        
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handle)))
        
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLAyer)
    }
    
    @objc func handle(){
        let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        basicAnimation.toValue = 1
        
        basicAnimation.duration = 3
        
        shapeLAyer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic")
        
        
    }

}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Your question is not clear and undertable. can you please clear more?

Comment: above code: when I click the screen there is a circle progress bar that works. I want to reach the number 300. For this, I press the button as 0 -1-2-3 -... -300, starting from 0 in the circle in the label. I want the circle bar to move every time I press

Comment: You mean if the total value is 300 and I pressed the 150 number button then half-circle is filled and when I pressed 100 then progress will be shown according to the number right?

Comment: just like that:) but the numbers will increase one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this type of progress by setting proper from value, to value and with the mode of `CABasicAnimation`

Here, I take two var one for total number (for total progress) and one for current progress number.

From these two var, I converted this value to between 0-1.

First, in your code `UIBezierPath` angle is wrong.
Replace this line by

```
let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: 3*CGFloat.pi / 2, clockwise: true)
```

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // Other code
    
    private let totalNumber: CGFloat = 300.0
    private var currentProgressNumber: CGFloat = 0
    private let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    
    // viewDidLoad code
    
    func playAnimation(){
        if currentProgressNumber > totalNumber || currentProgressNumber < 0 {
            return
        }
        basicAnimation.fromValue = basicAnimation.toValue
        basicAnimation.toValue = currentProgressNumber/totalNumber
        basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        basicAnimation.duration = 3
        basicAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.both
        shapeLAyer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic")
    }
    
    @IBAction func onIncrement(_ sender: UIButton) {
        currentProgressNumber += 15 //<-- Change your increment interval here
        playAnimation()
    }
    
    @IBAction func onDecrement(_ sender: UIButton) {
        currentProgressNumber -= 15 //<-- Change your increment interval here
        playAnimation()
    }
}
```

Note: Replace your animation function with `playAnimation()` and also change the increment-decrement value as per your requirement for testing I used 15.

[image]

Comment: the only problem is completing without 300. At 255, the flat was full. Thank you for your interest. If we solve this too, this is ok :)

Comment: It’s not possible. Can you please attach SS?

Comment: because I am not change   'endAngle: 3 * CGFloat.pi / 2'   :(.  I'm sorry. Raja thank you very much. you are good man.

Comment: Yes. This one need to correct in your code